# Java Error symbol not found (method addButton) , how to solve this?

Tags: java, swing

What I tried so far : trying to import my custom class ( but they are under the same folder , so it works as a package (I think , I am new to Java).
My custom class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class login extends JFrame{

private ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

public login(final int WIDTH , final int HEIGHT){
    this.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    //this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public addButton(final int WIDTH , final int HEIGHT){
    buttons.add(new JButton());
    buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1).setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.add(buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1));
   }
}
```

My Main class :

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final int WIDTH = 600;
        final int HEIGHT = 800;
        login Application = new login(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        Application.addButton(200, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the full stacktrace?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Also read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, variable names start lowerCase. You are just reversing that, making your code much harder to read.

Comment: @GhostCat This is the whole code and obviously I cannot call my own method , just like the title says , also Conventions are not a must , and as you can tell , I’m a beginner .

Comment: Although there is no rule saying that conventions must be followed, but generally this makes it easier for others to understand you and your codes. It's like driving on soil road in a countryside where you drive against convention when you see another car in the opposite direction.

Comment: At this moment, we are still not sure what problem you are facing. Is this an error that your compiler (IDE) is telling you? Or is there some exception thrown when the application runs? What is the exact message?

Comment: @Jai I use ubuntu terminal and the error message is Symbol not found : Application.addButton(int,int)

Comment: @GhostCat Yes it bothers me , that some people just post links about how to post (which is a good thing to do ) but in my case , I posted my entire code , YES it’s this small , just started doing it , but I am facing a wall I couldn’t overcome with google searches . Like I cannot give you more from my code because it is the WHOLE code , and you post something like “Minimal ,  Complete , and Verifiable” . I bet you didn’t even try running it .

Comment: It is not only about code. It is about **error messages**. The whole point is that a posting that *forces* people to download and compile themselves doesn't help future readers. You really want to make sure that all error information is **clearly** visible from your question.

Comment: @GhostCat it literally says in the title, by the way someone answered , I am retarded for missing out the return type , I apologize for my behaviour but I seriously do believe what I’ve said , and look at the answer , and review your comments.

Comment: You put fragments of the error message in the title. Instead or additionally , simply quote the complete error message in the question. Most often the message also points out the line number. Which you could then somehow mark within the code you put in the question. These are all small things that are easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the return type declaration for the method addButton(int, int). Try this:

```
public void addButton(final int WIDTH , final int HEIGHT) {
    buttons.add(new JButton());
    buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1).setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.add(buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you !  I don’t know how I’ve made this silly mistake.

Comment: @Gameerik Glad that you got your answer. Generally I would definitely recommend getting an IDE. The IDE would have screamed at you the *instant* you did this kind of careless mistake.

Comment: @Jai I am using VSCode , with the RedHat extension because eclipse doesn’t work for some reason , however i compile in the terminal